# What are water fats and complex fats and how to get rid of them?

Tags: body-fat, fat

I heard about complex fat and about water fat which is not that hard to get rid of as complex fat.
I would like to know more about them and how to get rid of them and how to know if my fats are complex or water fats.

Comment: I have never heard of these, can you link to an article or some other resource describing them?

Comment: I heard about them from a friend but not sure of it so i decide to ask about it .. and before i heard about having to much water over abs that make it look like fat!! not really sure about that too .. so i ask here to get anser from professionals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of the term "water fat" or "complex fat". However there are two common ways that people will divide human body fat: classing it as either brown or white fat or abdominal or subcutaneous fat.

## Brown fat vs. White fat

[White adipose tissute (i.e White fat)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_adipose_tissue) is the most common type of body fat in humans, and makes up nearly all body fat in adults. When people think of body fat, this is what they picture - a calorie rich storage mechanism. It has a small function in thermoregulation of body temperature through insultation, but is promarily a calorie storage tissue.

[Brown adipose tissue (i.e Brown fat)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_adipose_tissue) is a relatively new discover. In humans brown fat only really appears in measurable amounts in new born children. Before they learn to shiver, brown fat is a tissue that consumes calories to actively (rather than passively) produce body heat. It is very rare to seen naturally occuring in adult humans, and some research is being performed to see if we can promote brown fat growth in adults to help weight loss.

## Abdominal vs Subcutaneous fat

The other main way people classify fat is less about its makeup and more about its position in the body.

[Subcutaneous fat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adipose_tissue) is excess fat that is stored under the skin, but above muscles and away from organs. Again this is the classic picture of what people think of as fat - the folds on your body you can grab.

[Abdominal fat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_obesity) is excess fat that resides within the abdominal cavity, that is underneath your abs. This is primarily the same tissue as subcutaneous fat. The main difference is the health risks related to abdominal obesity, however this is difficult to isolate, as if you have large amounts of abdominal fat you most likely already have large amounts of subcutaneous fat as well.

## In the end it doesn't matter what type of fat you have

It is a [myth that you can target where you lose fat](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Myths.html). Fat gain and loss is a systemic change that is related to your genetics and hormones. If you are looking at getting healthy minimising your fat will minimise it systemically, and in ways that are most benficial. You can never get rid of fat completely, even abdominal fat and fats around organs are important for hormone regulation.

**Just eat healthy, exercise, and aim to lose fat - but don't stress on where or how the fat comes off and you will be pleased with the results.**

Comment: nice answer. As far as abdominal fat (aka omentum, visceral fat, or belly fat) and subcutaneous fat being the same, [this article](http://www.sharecare.com/health/weight-loss/article/bad-body-fat-omentum-definition-causes-prevention) may give a better distinction between the two, and why omentum fat is more harmful to your health than subcutaneous fat.  (The article also makes mention of a third type of fat in the bloodstream - triglycerides.)  Although you can't isolate the omentum from subcutaneous fat, tracking your waist measurement will show if your fat loss is on the right track.